# Proof of well-known principle used in the investment industry for compliance criteria

Tags: linear-algebra

I work in the financial services industry.  Presently I am involved in more than one project involving the monitoring and reporting on compliance of investment portfolios.

A principle that is accepted and happens to be useful in compliance calculations is as follows:

If a portfolio $P_{top}$, having market value $M_{P_{top}}$ is made up of $n$ underlying portfolios $P_1$ to $P_n$, such that:

$$
M_{P_{top}} = \sum_i^n M_{P_{top},P_i}
$$

where $M_{P_{top},P_i}$ is the market value that $P_{top}$ has invested in $P_i$; and we are interested in knowing whether or not some category of asset $C$ within $P_{top}$ exceeds some designated threshold $b_{c}$, we can know that the threshold *won't* be exceeded provided that $b_c$ is not exceeded for each $C_i$ within $P_i$.  If one or more of the underlying portfolios does have a $C_i$ that exceeds the threshold then all bets are off.  Note that $b_c < 1$.

Empirically, this is easy to show.  I'm looking for the formal mathematical proof of this though.

Comment: How are the $M$'s and $P$'s related?  They look to be the same

Comment: @RossMillikan, it's just a convention; $P$'s represent the portfolios, $M$'s represent the corresponding market values.

Comment: For all intents and purposes, $P$'s are there to *represent* the portfolios, but shouldn't participate in any equations.  So, I suppose, to avoid confusion, $M_{top}$ should be $M_{P_{top}}$.

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for $\frac {M_{top}}{P_{top}}=\sum_i \frac {M_i}{P_{top}}=\sum_i\frac {M_i}{P_i}\frac{P_i}{P_{top}}\lt \sum_i b_c\frac {P_i}{P_{top}}=b_c$